# How do I avoid IPV6 errors when trying to use kylemanna/openvpn image

Tags: docker, openvpn

I am trying to run the following deploy command...

```
docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn -d -p 1194:1194/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN kylemanna/openvpn
```

I get

> Sysctl error for disable_ipv6, please run docker with '--sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0'

So I run

```
docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn -d -p 1194:1194/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 kylemanna/openvpn
```

But I get

> Sysctl error for default forwarding, please run docker with '--sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1'

So I try...

```
docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn -d -p 1194:1194/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1 kylemanna/openvpn
```

But it doesn't take the sysctl value...

> Sysctl error for all forwarding, please run docker with '--sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1'

So I tried other variations...

```
docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn -d -p 1194:1194/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --sysctl "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1" kylemanna/openvpn
docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn -d -p 1194:1194/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1 kylemanna/openvpn
docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn -d -p 1194:1194/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0,net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1 kylemanna/openvpn
```

But none seem to work. How do I turn off ipv6 for the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case others have the same issue they looked the same but not quite. The actual command that works is...

```
docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn -d -p 1194:1194/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1 --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1 kylemanna/openvpn
```